# Babel: problem after update

Tags: babel

With babel 3.42 all works fine. After update babel don’t compile with lualatex (but compiles with xelatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
```

Error

luahyphenrules.sty error line 106 Undefined control sequence. Repeat

Comment: why are you using xgreek instead of directly babel?

Comment: That probably happened when a few things in the bits of `babel` that are loaded into the LaTeX kernel were cleaned up. Report this to the maintainer of [`luahyphenrules`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luahyphenrules) (who is incidentally also the maintainer of `babel`).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I don't know anything about babel.

Comment: which sounds a bit odd regarding the title of your question. Why don't you check the documentation?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I updated the packages one by one and the problem arose when babel was updated.

Comment: @moewe I do not know how to report the problem to the maintainer (my English is also not good).

Comment: According to the `luahyphenrules` documentation, the website of the developer is http://www.texnia.com/ and you can contact the author via the form at http://www.texnia.com/contact.html

Comment: @moewe I reported the problem to the maintainer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the update of luahyphenrules by Javier Bezos the problem was solved.
Thank you Javier Bezos!

P.S.

In the meantime I followed Ulrike Fischer's suggestion and I replaced the command

```
\usepackage{xgreek}
```

by

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
```

and it worked wonderfully.
Thank you Ulrike Fischer!